# Unique event tracking of link clicks does not equal the unique page views on my website

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking, analytics-events

I am tracking all link clicks from my pricing page through to my registration page using events in GA.

I have noticed that when viewing the traffic to my registration page, the number of unique page views coming from the pricing page does not match the number of unique events from the links clicked on the pricing page (I would have expected these to be equal).

Is it possible that there is some discrepancy within my own GA account or am I misunderstanding the relationship between unique events and unique page views?

If anyone has a suggestion here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big of a discrepancy are we looking at?

Comment: @nyuen 25% more unique page views from pricing to reg. than unique events from the same.

Answer (score 1):

> **Clicks and Sessions are different metrics.** Google AdWords tracks Clicks, while Analytics tracks Sessions. If a user clicks on your ad
>   twice within thirty minutes without closing his or her browser, this
>   is registered by Analytics as one session, even if the user left your
>   site and then returned shortly after. For example, if a user clicks on
>   your ad once, clicks the back button, and then clicks your ad again,
>   AdWords registers two clicks while Analytics registers one session.

More about this on [Data discrepancies between AdWords and Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034383?hl=en)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this applies to the OP's question?

Comment: @WendiT thanks for your input. I'm not using Adwords for this case. I have links to the reg. page on my pricing and am tracking them in Analytics using click events. Unique clicks to the reg. page are 25% less than unique views from the Pricing page (using previous page path filter in GA) which is a fair discrepancy in my books :\ - Thanks for your time